# Passing external variable to Mongo query [aggregate]

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create reusable script in pymongo that can be leveraged for future applications with a minimal change to the script. Trying to pass external variable to aggregate function which has $unwind, $objectToArray, $Project. I tried all methods as per the MongoDB manual but no luck.

Ex: Parent_Key='abc'
elements_list = "key1": "$abc.Key1", "Key2":"$abc.Key2" etc.

below is the command

db.test.aggregate([{"$unwind": Parent_Key},{"$addfields":{"abcrecordexists": {"gt":[{"$size":{"$objectToArray": "abc"}},0}]}}},{"$match": {"abcrecordexists":{"$gt": 0}}}, {"$project": {"_id": 1, elements_list}}])

I am trying pass the above declared parameters to the above query. Ran in to is not a defined name. As I am  new to Mongo, it would be great help.

Comment: Please include a full stack trace of any error

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Its erroring out NameError: name 'Parent_Key' is not defined. After read the manual from MongoDB to put $$ infront of variable if its external variable to Mongo Query, its erroring out with unrecognized option to $unwind stage: $let with error code 28811

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can pass a parameter, you just need to make sure the types and syntax are correct. Hopefully this gives an idea:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({'list': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

list_to_unwind = '$list'
projection = {'_id': 0}

agg = db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': list_to_unwind},
    {'$project': projection}
])
```

Comment: I tried the above option and running in to the following error. bson.errors.invalidDocument:cannot encode object: of type <class set>, I am trying to pass the concatenated key to the "$project" . I am not sure what I am missing.